# Perl: How to save keys order from hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to display the keys from json hash

After execution, I got all the keys displayed but with different order. I got stuck at that point.

Is there any possibility to save the keys order?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to save them seperately, like in another array or something. The point of a hash is to not have the order of keys be important...

Comment: @AntonH So, is there any way to use an array instead of hash for the json: so that I can save the order?

Comment: Then don't use a hash to store your parsed data, store it inside an array instead. Or better yet, use a JSON module for parsing and don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @user6039980 Depends on how you read the JSON. If you do it "manually", you would have to do it yourself at some point. If it's an automatic library, then you may have to play around with it to get the keys in order. You may also have to consider if conserving the order is important enough to spend time working on it, or if you can work around it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a list (which would be ordered) and in each list element put another list with 2 fields (key and value).  That is effectively an ordered hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%json = qw(key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3);
my $result = "keys => { \n";
for my $key (keys %json) {
  $result .= "$key\n";
}
$result .= " }\n\n";

print $result;

my $json=[];
for my $key (sort keys %json) {
    my @list = ();
    push(@list,$key);
    push(@list,$json{$key});
    push(@$json,\@list);
}

for (@$json) {
    print $_->[0], " ", $_->[1], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my case the json needs to be retrieved from a file, not manually: so I need a method working with 'decode_json'.

Comment: Just write your own decode_json, which wraps the original but does the extra bit of converting to a list.  I suspect you shouldn't be doing what your trying to do.  There is no requirement for JSON to be ordered.

Comment: I needed ordering just for testing. But it's ok now. I will ignore the order. Thanks, that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A Hash by definition has no order. This is true of Perl hashes and JSON structures. In Perl, the order of the keys in the hash may not be the same as the way they were added to the hash. Two JSON structures can be equivalent to each other, but not the same.

If you need the keys in a specific order, use `sort` to sort the keys in the order you want when you examine them.

Answer (score 0):

See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366750/perl-decode-and-encode-json-preserving-order/77079473#77079473) for a solution to keeping JSON keys in their original order in Perl.