# perl decode and encode json preserving order

Tags: json, perl, hash

I have in a text database field a json encoded chart configuration in the form of:

```
{"Name":[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]],"Name2":[[3,2]]}
```

The first number of these IDs is a primary key of another table. I'd like to remove those entries with a trigger when the row is deleted, a plperl function would be good except it does not preserve the order of the hash and the order is important in this project. What can I do (without changing the format of the json encoded config)? Note: the chart name can contain any characters so it's hard to do it with regex.

Comment: JSON.org: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." If you want to preserve order, use an array instead of an object. Then, just grep to keep all but the item you want to remove.

Comment: Every perl JSON parser I've looked at represents JSON objects as hash tables, which, of course, don't preserve order. It's not something you can really rely on with JSON objects in general as already mentioned. Maybe use an array if order matters?

Comment: The problem is that the website is written in PHP which preserves the order so that is how the order of the charts are saved. I'm not aware that there would be a plphp for postgres so I guess I could do a system() call from a plperl function but that would be a horribe solution.

Comment: I looked into JSON::PP code and I'd just need to add a tie to IxHash at the beginning of the function called object(). I can't believe no one ever needed that! Having to modify OS povided files introduces more problems than it solves so I'll just modify my json in PHP right after deletion and hope no one will delete more data anywhere else or calls my cleanup function. How wondeful. Or should I go with the plperl system() call from the trigger? I'm between a rock and a hard place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a streaming JSON decoder, such as `JSON::Streaming::Reader`. You could then store your JSON as an array of key/value pairs, instead of a hash.

The actual implementation of how you might use do this is highly dependent on the structure of your data, but given the simple example provided... here's a simple implementation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::Streaming::Reader;
use JSON 'to_json';

my $s = '{"Name":[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]],"Name2":[[3,2]]}';

my $jsonr = JSON::Streaming::Reader->for_string($s);

my @data;
while (my $token = $jsonr->get_token) {
    my ($key, $value) = @$token;
    if ($key eq 'start_property') {
        push @data, { $value => $jsonr->slurp };
    }   
}   

print to_json(\@data);
```

The output for this script is always: -

```
[{"Name":[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]]},{"Name2":[[3,2]]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the gist of what you are doing here, so I accepted your response because it's a lot more general than what I was doing before and I can reformat the data to what I want.

Answer (score 3):

@soger, thanks for the idea in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366750/perl-decode-and-encode-json-preserving-order/77079473#comment89714954_51366750) above from 5 years ago!

> I looked into JSON::PP code and I'd just need to add a tie to IxHash at the beginning of the function called object().

Brilliant solution!  Thanks for the idea.  I figured out how to implement this using the `Monkey::Patch` module to wrap the `JSON::PP::object()` function to make it use `Tie::IxHash`, without touching the installed `JSON::PP` files:

```perl
use Monkey::Patch qw[patch_package];

# Monkey-patch JSON::PP::object() subroutine to use Tie::IxHash.
my $handle = patch_package 'JSON::PP' => 'object' => sub {
  my $orig = shift;
  my %obj;
  tie %obj, 'Tie::IxHash' or die "tie(\%obj, 'Tie::IxHash') failed!\n";
  $orig->(\%obj)
};
```

After running the code above, as long as `$handle` remains in scope, `JSON::PP::decode_json` will use Tie::IxHash for all JSON objects.  I tested by reading in a JSON file, decoding it with `JSON::PP::decode_json`, then encoded the resulting data structure back into JSON with `JSON::PP::encode_json` and wrote that to a new JSON file.  I then ran the original JSON file and the new JSON file through `jq .` to normalize the formatting and compared the results.  They were 100% byte-for-byte identical.

(Of course, ideally `JSON::PP` should offer this as a built-in option out of the box!)

Comment: Monkey::Patch, I like that! I didn't know about it. I ended up creating a TiedJSON package which messed with the original JSON::PP package's namespace putting new functions like a tied_decode_json() in it and my TiedJSON package has a decode_json() too which calls that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to solve my problem, but it's not a general solution so it will probably not help the casual reader. Anyway I got the order of keys using the help of the database, I called my function like this:

```
SELECT remove_from_chart(
    chart_config,
    array(select * from json_object_keys(chart_config::json)),
    id);
```

then I walked through the keys in the order of the second parameter and put the results in a new tied (IxHash) hash and json encoded it.

It's pretty sad that there is no perl json decoder that could preserve the key order when everything else I work with, at least on this project, does it (php, postgres, firefox, chrome).

Comment: I asked the developer of JSON::PP if he'd add an option to tie to IxHash every hash created during the decode and the answer was "Sorry, no." I wish I understood why this is such a taboo.

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are unordered. You will have to encode the desired order into your data somehow

```
{"Name":[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]],"Name2":[[3,2]], "__order__":["Name","Name2"]}

[{"Name":[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]]},{"Name2":[[3,2]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want streaming decoder of JSON data like SAX parser. If so then see [`JSON::Streaming::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Streaming::Reader), or [`JSON::SL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::SL).